# Toggling between hide and show and hiding div on mouse up

Tags: jquery, html, toggle

I have a Login link and on clicking of it, a div will be displayed. On clicking the link, I want to toggle between hide and show of that div. Also I need to hide the div once user clicks outside the div.

What I have done is shown below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#poplink").click(function() {
        $('#popup').toggle();
    });
    $(document).mouseup(function(e) {
        var container = $("#popup");
        if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0) { // if the target of the click isn't the container...
            // ... nor a descendant of the container
            container.hide();
        }
    });
});
```

The problem now is I am not able to toggle between hide and show. When I click outside the div, it is hiding perfectly.

Can anyone help me to solve this. [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/f9Ywh/)

Comment: You may want to see this http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form

Comment: `$('#regpopup').hide();` seems not used, so redundant

Comment: @dan I believe the OP just did not copy over the code for the `#regpopup`.

Comment: I have other div regpopup with the same property. So I didn't copied the code for it. sorry for the mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Register a click handler for the docuement instead of mouseup

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#poplink").click(function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        $('#popup').toggle();
        $('#regpopup').hide();
    });

    $(document).click(function (e) {
        var container = $("#popup");
        if (!container.is(e.target) // if the target of the click isn't the container...
        &&
        container.has(e.target).length === 0) // ... nor a descendant of the container
        {
            container.hide();
        }
    });

});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/uj9PB/)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the idea. I hope the behavior is consistent over all browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, I see where you copied that bit. Changed it for you, so now it works:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $("#poplink").click(function(e)
  {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('#popup').toggle();
    $('#regpopup').hide();
  });
  $("*:not(#poplink)").click(function (e) {
    var container = $("#popup");
    if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0)
    {
      container.hide();
    }
  });
});
```

And the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/f9Ywh/8/

Comment: I want to toggle between hide/show of the div on click of the link. That is what I am not getting.

Comment: hmm, useful. awesome!